# Concurrent access to vector from multiple threads using a mutex lock

Tags: rust

I'm using an example provided by the Tokio library and attempting to have a vector of all the currently active TCP connections. Ultimately, I would like to be able to broadcast a message to each of the active connections, by looping through them and writing a message to the socket.

To start with, I am trying to print out the current number of connections in one thread whilst accepting connections in another.

To do this, I'm trying to use a shared vector. I've not yet implemented the removal of connections from the vector as and when they disconnect.

```
// A tiny async echo server with tokio-core
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use tokio_io::{io, AsyncRead};
use tokio_core::net::TcpListener;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    // Create the event loop that will drive this server
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    // Bind the server's socket
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12345".parse().unwrap();
    let tcp = TcpListener::bind(&addr, &handle).unwrap();

    let mut connections = Arc::new((Mutex::new(Vec::new())));

    thread::spawn(move || {
        //Every 10 seconds print out the current number of connections
        let mut i;
        loop {              
          i = connections.lock().unwrap().len();
          println!("There are {} connections", i);
          stdout().flush();
          thread::sleep_ms(10000);
        }
    });



    // Iterate incoming connections
    let server = tcp.incoming().for_each(|(tcp, _)| {

        connections.lock().unwrap().push(tcp);
        // Split up the read and write halves
        let (reader, writer) = tcp.split();

        // Future of the copy
        let bytes_copied = io::copy(reader, writer);

        // ... after which we'll print what happened
        let handle_conn = bytes_copied.map(|(n, _, _)| {
            println!("wrote {} bytes", n)
        }).map_err(|err| {
            println!("IO error {:?}", err)
        });

        // Spawn the future as a concurrent task
        handle.spawn(handle_conn);

        Ok(())
    });

    // Spin up the server on the event loop
    core.run(server).unwrap();

}
```

At the moment this is failing to build with the following errors:

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `connections`
  --> src/main.rs:36:42
   |
26 |     thread::spawn(move || {
   |                   ------- value moved (into closure) here
...
36 |     let server = tcp.incoming().for_each(|(tcp, _)| {
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^ value captured here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `connections` has type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::vec::Vec<tokio_core::net::TcpStream>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `tcp`
  --> src/main.rs:40:32
   |
38 |         connections.lock().unwrap().push(tcp);
   |                                          --- value moved here
39 |         // Split up the read and write halves
40 |         let (reader, writer) = tcp.split();
   |                                ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `tcp` has type `tokio_core::net::TcpStream`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Is it possible to achieve this without writing any unsafe code?

Answer (score 11):

You get the first error because of the move closure:

```
let mut connections = Arc::new((Mutex::new(Vec::new())));
thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut i = connections.lock().unwrap().len();
    ....
}
```

This actually moves the whole `Arc`, while you only want to move "a part" of it (that is, move it in such a way that the reference count is incremented, and that both threads can use it).

To do this, we can use `Arc::clone`:

```
let mut connections = Arc::new((Mutex::new(Vec::new())));
let conn = connections.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut i = conn.lock().unwrap().len();
    ....
}
```

This way, the cloned `Arc`, `conn`, is moved into the closure, and the original `Arc`, `connections`, is not, and hence still usable.

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing with your second error, but for the sake of simply counting the connections you do not need to `push` the entire thing.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! As mentioned in the question, ultimately I would like to be able to have a vector of all the currently active connections and be able to iterate through the vector and broadcast a message to each of them. Will it be possible to push onto the vector each tcp connection ?

Comment: You could try to wrap the connection in an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` as you did with the vector, but this limits what you can do with it (eg. you cannot move it in the `.split` call).

Comment: I realised I missed out the loop from the first thread. Perhaps it will make more sense now.