# How to tell Rust to let me modify a shared variable hidden behind an RwLock?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Safe [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html) demands the following from all references:

1. One or more references (`&T`) to a resource,
2. Exactly one mutable reference (`&mut T`).

I want to have one `Vec` that can be read by multiple threads and written by one, but only one of those should be possible at a time (as the language demands).

So I use an `RwLock`.

I need a `Vec<i8>`. To let it outlive the main function, I `Box` it and then I `RwLock` around *that*, like thus:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let val = RwLock::new(Box::new(v));
    for i in 0..10 {
        thread::spawn(move || threadFunc(&val));
    }
    loop {
        let mut VecBox = (val.write().unwrap());
        let ref mut v1 = *(*VecBox);
        v1.push(1);
        //And be very busy.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000));
    }
}
fn threadFunc(val: &RwLock<Box<Vec<i8>>>) {
    loop {
        //Use Vec
        let VecBox = (val.read().unwrap());
        let ref v1 = *(*VecBox);
        println!("{}", v1.len());
        //And be very busy.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

Rust refuses to compile this:

```
 capture of moved value: `val`
   --> src/main.rs:14:43
      |
   14 |         thread::spawn(move || threadFunc(&val));
      |                       -------             ^^^ value captured here after move
      |                       |
      |                       value moved (into closure) here
```

Without the thread:

```
for i in 0..10 {
    threadFunc(&val);
}
```

It compiles. The problem is with the closure. I have to "move" it, or else Rust complains that it can outlive `main`, I also can't clone `val` (`RwLock` doesn't implement `clone()`).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there's no structural difference between using a `RwLock` and a `Mutex`; they just have different access patterns. See 
[Concurrent access to vector from multiple threads using a mutex lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428512/155423) for related discussion.

The problem centers around the fact that you've transferred ownership of the vector (in the `RwLock`) to some thread; therefore your main thread doesn't *have it anymore*. You can't access it because it's gone.

In fact, you'll have the same problem as you've tried to pass the vector to each of the threads. You only have one vector to give away, so only one thread could have it.

You need *thread-safe shared ownership*, provided by [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let val = Arc::new(RwLock::new(v));

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let v = val.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || thread_func(v));
    }

    for _ in 0..5 {
        {
            let mut val = val.write().unwrap();
            val.push(1);
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}

fn thread_func(val: Arc<RwLock<Vec<i8>>>) {
    loop {
        {
            let val = val.read().unwrap();
            println!("{}", val.len());
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
}
```

Other things to note:

1. I removed the infinite loop in `main` so that the code can actually finish.
2. I fixed **all of the compiler warnings**. If you are going to use a compiled language, pay attention to the warnings.

   - unnecessary parentheses
   - `snake_case` identifiers. Definitely **do not** use `PascalCase` for local variables; that's used for types. `camelCase` does not get used in Rust.
3. I added some blocks to shorten the lifetime that the read / write locks will be held. Otherwise there's a lot of contention and the child threads never have a chance to get a read lock.
4. `let ref v1 = *(*foo);` is non-idiomatic. Prefer `let v1 = &**foo`. You don't even need to do that at all, thanks to `Deref`.

Comment: Thanks, although wouldn't it be more idiomatic to `drop()` variables rather than to hack scope?

Comment: @CharlesShiller See [What are the options to end a mutable borrow in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/1233251). So no, blocks are as idiomatic as you can get.

Comment: @E_net4 in this case, `drop` should work because the lock doesn't look like a mutable borrow. I don't know that *either* is more idiomatic than the other here; `drop(vec)` just looks strange to me though.

Comment: Also, maybe it's the C in me, but is `&**foo` different than `*foo`?

Comment: @CharlesShiller see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/155423 for full details. TL;DR, Rust has the `Deref` trait, which means that `&*` isn't always a no-op.